# Hadoop MapReduce Job locally cannot load libraries and fails the connection on OS X

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, osx-yosemite

I am trying to run hadoop on OS X Yosemite. While I was following the instructions from  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html, I configured hadoop, and started $ sbin/start-dfs.sh, and then checking with jps got the output:

```
17237 DataNode
17324 SecondaryNameNode
17388 Jps
```

However, when, I tried "bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user", hadoop could not load libraries (the same happening also while I was running other examples), and showed the failed connection:

```
$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
15/01/05 03:19:35 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Call From *.local/192.*.*.* to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like namenode is not running. In HDFS, namenode is the one which act as master daemon and take care of all requests from HDFS clients. Namenode should have been started when you executed start-dfs.sh script. Check if you have formatted HDFS before starting hdfs services, If HDFS was not formatted, format HDFS using the following command and stop and start HDFS service again using the commands stop-dfs.sh and start-dfs.sh

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: basically, I needed to stop ($ sbin/stop-dfs.sh), format ($ bin/hdfs namenode -format) and then start again ($ sbin/start-dfs.sh). However, the problem with loading native-hadoop libraries remain.

Comment: Loading native-hadoop library is not a problem, It's just a warning, this won't impact any hadoop performance. You may ignore this warning. If you really wanted to handle this warnning, you need to build hadoop native library and supply the binary while starting HDFS.